# Cocoa drag plus cursor not always shown

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTableView that is registered to catch dragging to external files to it. The plus cursor (copy) is shown at first, but it the mouse leaves the table and than returns, the cursor does not changes back to the plus cursor.

How can i make sure the right cursor will be shown?

Comment: Which dragging-related methods are you implementing?